# Call data without for loop from database

Tags: python, html, django

How do I call data from the database without the for loop in a HTML file?
I'm a beginner and in all tutorials I could find they use the for loop.

But I want to get a URL from my database and post it only once in the HTML file, but I don't want to hardcode it in the file.
So in my models.py my class looks like this

```
class Weburl(models.Model):
    source = models.URLField(max_length=200)
```

In my views.py I call this

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    songs = Songs.objects.all()
    contacts = Contacts.objects.all()
    url = Weburl.objects.all()

    context = {'songs': songs, 'contacts': contacts, 'url': url}

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Of course you need to import the stuff in views.py.

Now I can call the songs, contacts and url in a for loop. But I don't want to call url as a for loop. So what needs to be changed?
Other question, does it make senses to save the songs and contacts in the context variable?

If anyone knows what to do, it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: html is rendered on the client side.  If you have a for loop in your html you are executing <% python code%> on the server side before the html is rendered.  Depending on what you are doing you can either just execute your database execute inside <% %> or execute it in your application.py file

Comment: The post is somewhat confusing. Are you trying to get a specific URL? Then don't pull `objects.all()`, specify the `pk` that you want.

Comment: I agree with @Hayden -- what's wrong with `for` loops?